# Autostarting iOS and Android apps soon after install

Tags: android, ios, installation, launch

I have a requirement to start an application as soon as it is installed. It should start without any user intervention like "Open" button press etc.

I cannot jailbreak the phone as it is an enterprise application. Requirement is install the app and it launches directly soon after that. Is this possible to do this without jailbreaking?

And also I need to achieve same thing on android side.

Comment: as for as iOS concern it is not possible legally

Comment: In general we encourage posters to explain what they have found in their research. Have you looked into this at all? If not, your preferred search engine is the best place to start.

Comment: @OsamaSadiq.. if not legally means?? How can it be done illegally. Jailbreak is an exception coz we are working on an in house application and we are not supposed to jailbreak the code.  thanks in advance

Comment: then Dear it is not possible .  .it is handled by OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, after the AppStore installed the there is code run by the system to start your app.

Also on iOS you can only start other apps or your now app if it has a App URL Scheme. But since after install there isn't any code run you will not be able to call the App URL scheme to start your app.

To my knowledge this is the same on Android.

Comment: Thanks .But we dont upload to Appstore however. its an inhouse app for some testing purpose. So was looking for any ways to achieve this thing.

Comment: Same problem, there is not callback after installing the app, the only thing you could to is keep trying to open the custom app URL scheme.

Comment: can u explain wat this means from your reply.. keep trying to open the custom app URL scheme

Comment: For example your app has the app scheme `my-app:\\` then try and open this scheme in javascript. If there is an error the app could not be started and you should try again in X seconds.

Comment: This means that we need to Jailbreak is it?

Comment: No you just open the URL (app sheme) via javascript and try and open the app.

Comment: I am new to iOS. Can you redirect me to some document which explains about this scheme clearly.. that would be of great help..

Comment: I've never done it my self, but the iOS part can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html The Javascript part you will have to find some where else.

Comment: Bro I might be bothering you. Please give me a little more information.If we r writing a javascript code where to write it??within the app? or by a separate app? or any sort of desktop app? or is this just a app to app communication?

Comment: The website that is delivering you InHouse app that is where you write the javascript code.